# HttpFormUrlEncodedContent for byte[] encoded string raise an error

Tags: c#, http, win-universal-app

I'm creating an `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` *"Key, Value"*. One of this *Value* that I am passing is an `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesResult);` where byteResult is `byte[]`.

This *Value* could have some of this chars "if\u000f\0+*,\"[j"

When I'm trying to encode this `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` with `HttpFormUrlEncodedContent`, I got an `System.ArgumentException` where the exception message is *"Value does not fall within the expected range."*

```
var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    ...
};

var content = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
```

### Edit 1

Add an example of byte[] that I get from ZXing Barcode Scanner.

[image]

Comment: The "if\u000f\0+*,\"[j" string is not a valid string. When you use HttpFormUrlEncodedContent with "\0" in your chars it will throw the exception. So please post your code, how do you get the chars "if\u000f\0+*,\"[j".

Comment: With this method `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesResult)` where byteResult is `bytes[]`

Comment: I know it get from byte[], I want know why is  the "\0" in your byte[]?

Comment: Hi @JaydenGu I updated my question.

Comment: Because it is use for HttpFormUrlEncodedContent, the "\u000f" is the "Shift" button that it has no meaning. And the "\0" is the end of the string, it is no useful in HttpFormUrlEncodedContent too.